# How to annotate a function in python that returning an html file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code I also tried it without quotes but it gives me ('html' is not defined) error

```
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to searchtools on the web!')
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how annotations work
`->` is a syntax meant to mention the `type` of data being returned.
To annotate functions there are various methods.

**Method 1: Commenting** *(also known as single line comment)*

```
def function(a): # Annotation
    return a
```

**Method 2: String Literal** *(also known as multi line or docstring comment)*

```
def function(a):
    """
    Returns the value passed
    """
    return a
```

Method 1 is recommend for small comments *(for your case)*
Method 2 is recommended for big comments

Comment: `->` isn't really an operator; it produces no value. Rather, it's just part of the syntax of a `def` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can really set anything, but in these scenarios I find it useful to add a comment as a return type. In my case PyCharm also seems to understand that i'm adding a comment and it removes the warnings, as it knows that is indeed fine to do.

Eaxmple:

```
def entry_page() -> 'some kind of valid html':
    return ...  # something here
```

Comment: Though it works, it's not something appropriate. Most code editors would show errors (but the function would work) and even libraries don't use them.

Comment: While function annotations formerly had no required semantics, PEP-563 deprecates the use of anything other than PEP-484-style type hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Html` comes under `File` catogary which is `object` so right thing to do is.

```
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> object:
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to searchtools on the web!')
app.run()
```